# Find a list of panache entities from their corresponding ids

Tags: quarkus

I have a list of ids of a PanacheEntity. I want to find the list of PanacheEntities corresponding to these Id. Is there a built in or suggested API which can do this.

```
public class Person extends PanacheEntity {
  public String name;
}
```

After a previous search, I have with me a list of ids of the Person entity. I would now like to get a list of the Person objects in a single DB query.
I tried `Person.list("id", listOfIds)`, but this fails when there is more than one object in the list. Is there a better way than this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
Person.list("id in ?1", listOfIds)
```

Comment: Just a note in case anyone tries passing in `Long[] ids` you get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate orginal parameter [2], expecting one of [1]` which is fixed with `Arrays.asList(ids)`